# Is it OK to give an answer that employs external methods?

Tags: discussion

I suspect that this question is a duplicate, but I can't find it.

I was looking at [How can I respec my badass rank bonus stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85014/how-can-i-respec-my-badass-rank-bonus-stats) and did a bit of web-crawling on my own and seem to have found a solution. However, this solution requires a tool that is not provided or endorsed by the game. Is it OK to post it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is, we have many questions whose answers are to use an external tool, such as the variety of save game editing questions for the Mass Effect series, which require the use of the gibbed editor.

As long as your answer attempts to answer the question it should be sufficient as an answer, although in instances where there is a better way to do it (maybe not using an external tool), an answer revealing this will likely be more appropriate.

Comment: We also look down upon illegal options or solutions that involve cheating in certain scenarios.

Comment: Solutions involving cheating aren't allowed specifically in reference to multiplayer games as these are generally against the EULA for these kinds of game

Comment: I think SE should aim to answer questions in every possible way. I mean some prefer a cheat solution, some prefer using balanced mods and others want to use legit vanilla gameplay only. There are often   already solved questions but it should not hurt to add some not so obvious answers to this. As long as it answers the initial question of course.

Comment: Providing cheats for competitive multiplayer games should be frowned upon, but there is nothing wrong with cheating in single-player games.